# inno setup PrivilegesRequired lowest start menu

Tags: windows-10, inno-setup, startmenu

In Windows 10, with INNO setup, I have PrivilegesRequired=lowest and AlwaysUsePersonalGroup=yes, but do not get any Start Menu icons.  Is this correct behavior?  I there a way around it?

Comment: Show us [mcve].

Comment: Please delete this question. You have posted the same question again: [start menu for standard user, revisited](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47626044/850848), which is duplicate to [Installing application for currently logged in user from Inno Setup installer running as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47626044/850848).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry.  My mistake.  I must have been looking in the wrong place.  The start menu items actually do get created in C:\Users\standarduser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyProgram.  And they were created there with or without AlwaysUsePersonalGroup=yes.  Maybe there was a slight time delay before the icon group actually appeared in the Start button menu, or maybe I just did not see it.

Later found that with PrivilegesRequired=lowest, using right-click/Run-as-administrator while in a standard user account resulted in the start menu items getting created in the account of the admin user, and are not accessible to the standard user. Darn.